# Uniformly weak mixing transformations

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(X, T, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a nonatomic standard probability space equipped with a measure preserving transformation $T$. We say $T$ is *uniformly weak mixing* if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N > 0$ such that for all measurable sets $A, B \in \mathcal F$

$$| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(T^{-k} A \cap B) - \mu(A) \mu(B)| < \varepsilon$$

for all $n > N$.

**Question:** If $T$ is uniformly weak mixing, then does it hold that for all $f \in L^\infty (X)$, there exists some measurable set $E$ of full measure such that

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n T^k f \to \int f d\mu$$

uniformly on $E$?

Comment: I don't think there is a system that satisfies your definition of uniformly weak mixing.  Such a system must be ergodic, and therefore admit [Rohlin towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokhlin_lemma).  Given $N>0$ and a Rohlin tower $\{E,TE,\dots,T^{m-1}E\}$ with $N = o(m)$, you can set $A=B = E\cup TE \cup \cdots \cup T^{m/2}E$ and find that $\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{k=1}^{N+1} \mu(T^{-k} A\cap A) \approx \mu(A)\approx 1/2$. In other words, given an initial segment of integers, every ergodic MPS on a nonatomic probability space admits a subset which is approximately invariant under that segment.

Comment: Ah i see, that’s true indeed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John Griesmer answered this question: "I don't think there is a system that satisfies your definition of uniformly weak mixing. Such a system must be ergodic, and therefore admit Rohlin towers. Given $>0$ and a Rohlin tower $\{,,…,^{−1}\}$ with $=()$, you can set $==\cup  \cup \ldots \cup ^{/2}$ and find that $\frac{1}{+1}\sum^{+1}_{=1}\mu(^{−}\cap )\approx \mu()\approx 1/2$. In other words, given an initial segment of integers, every ergodic MPS on a nonatomic probability space admits a subset which is approximately invariant under that segment."